# How do I select a random row from rows that share the lowest column value?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

For example, from the following table I would want to select randomly from rows 2,4, and 5 because they share the lowest `view_count` value.

```
id    animal    view_count
1     bird      6
2     dog       3
3     cat       4
4     rat       3
5     bat       3
6     eel       7
```

I'm not sure how to piece this together.  I found

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

but then I can't order by `view_count ASC` (I don't think...).

Answer (score 1):

You can order by more than one value:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY view_count, RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

This will first order the table by `view_count`, and then randomize the order of the rows with the same `view_count`.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be working. However, it's running a bit slow. I'm working with a table with 10,000 rows. Is there a faster way? Would it be quicker to check for viewCount=0, if not exist, viewCount=1, etc and then get a random one with that value?

Comment: Sqlite behaves strangely when it comes to performance; you could try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE view_count = (SELECT MIN(view_count) FROM table) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;`, but it might be no better. You'll have to analyze the query and see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both versions of the query and they have about the same performance. Maybe this just necessarily take a long time for 10,000 rows. Maybe I'll make a static variable so that I will always search for viewCount = 0 and, if none are found, always search for viewCount = 1, etc. Thanks for the help!